# async/await replace in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to do a function like async/await in C# but in node js
I have found an [example](http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/bringing-asyncawait-to-life-in-javascript/) but It gives me an error.

here is the code

```
function* gotNews(response){    
        console.log("in gotNews");
        str='';
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });    
        response.on('end', function () {
              str = JSON.parse(str);
              console.log(str);
              fetchCategories();
        });
        return str;
}


function fetchNews(sourceURL){
        console.log("in fetch news");
             sourceURL = url.parse(sourceURL);
             console.log(sourceURL);
        var options = 
        {
            host: sourceURL.host,
            port: 134,
            path: sourceURL.path,

            method: 'GET',
        };
        var req = http.request(options,yield gotNews);//start request and recive response in gotSources
        req.end();
}
```

I am using the * yield operation but gives me an error

```
ErrorC:\Users\Alaa\Desktop\Fluid_layout_with_jQuery_Masonry\1\app.js:198
        var elnewselygat = yield gotNews();
                                 ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Comment: is it something special with function* (I mean STAR)? I never saw function declared like that

Comment: @tomekK The * in function* is your async keyword.
yield is your await keyword.

Comment: Oh, sorry for stupid question. I should check link first

Comment: As I said there is no such a thing native in JavaScript. The example which you show requires a custom library https://github.com/bjouhier/galaxy/ and I guess that it reads your functions and does some magic to remove the * sign.

Comment: I think you just need an ajax call ...

Comment: Have you tried promises? https://github.com/cujojs/when I know its not the same, but as far as I know, it helps you solve the same issue in a different way

Comment: Did you run `node` with the `--harmony` parameter? You'll also need node >= 0.11.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need generators *and* promises to make it as easy as `async`/`await`/`Task`.

As @Paul stated, generators are a "future feature" so you need to pass `--harmony` or `--harmony-generators`. Also, generators are supported in V8 3.19, which is only in Node.js 0.11.2 or newer.

The JavaScript community is currently considering a number of possible approaches; there's a good overview of several of them [here](http://jlongster.com/A-Study-on-Solving-Callbacks-with-JavaScript-Generators), and there are other libraries out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

check:
https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor-es6

It does what you want, with generators. (no promises required)

function* ----> c# async

yield wait.for(fn...) ---> c# await

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` with `babel --stage 1 --optional runtime`.